# Generalization of Bass-Serre Theory for pro-trees, $\Lambda$-trees, and $\mathbb R$-trees

Tags: group-theory, trees, geometric-group-theory

If a group $G$ acts on a tree $T$, then by Bass-Serre theory $G$ can be rewritten as the fundamental group of the graph of groups $G \backslash\!\backslash T$.

There are several approaches to generalizing a simplicial tree such as [pro-trees](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82620772.pdf), $\Lambda$-trees, and [$\mathbb R$-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree).

Is there an analog object like a graph of groups when you study a group acting on those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of $\mathbb R$-trees (which is a special case of $\Lambda$-trees), one should keep in mind that there exists a nontrivial, minimal action of a finitely generated group $G$ on an $\mathbb R$-tree $T$ such that every orbit of the action is dense. The quotient space $G \backslash\!\backslash T$ is therefore highly non-Hausdorff: it is an uncountable topological space in which every point is dense. So in lieu of some concrete alternative proposal regarding what a "graph of groups" description of such an example might consist of, for this example I would answer your question with a simple *No, there is no such description*.